# Derivative expression tree java

Tags: java, tree, derivative

I am trying to implement a method that returns a new tree expressing the derivative of an expression. I have the orignal expression tree, as well as an exact copy at my disposal. I know I can to this recursively using differentiation rules and base cases for when a node is a constant or a number. But I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to store the new expressions.

I don't need an exact answer, just some guidance/recommendations on how to store the new expression?

The diagram is helpful, thank you! I'm getting there, however still having trouble implementing working code.

```
  if(this.getValue().equals("mult")){
        this.deepCopy().setValue("add");
        this.deepCopy().getRightChild().setValue("mult");
        this.deepCopy().getLeftChild().setValue("mult");
        // not sure what to recursively here!

        }
```

Comment: What are you working in and what code do you have so far? You didn't tag your question with a programming language.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer is to use a language that was designed for symbolic manipulation of formulas. Hint: it started prior to 1960, and it's four letter word.

Hey check this out, it appears there are some new techniques in this area: http://www.autodiff.org/

http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~fateman/papers/ADIL.pdf

Comment: Oops, should have mentioned this is in Java.

Comment: I really do appreciate the python link, but that language is absolutely foreign to me unfortunately!

Answer (score 0):

Basically you start from the root of the original tree and work your way down, calculating derivatives for the nodes when it becomes necessary. For example, since D fg = f'g+fg', for a multiplication node you would output a sum of products:

```
           ....                   ....
             \                      \
              *                      +
             / \           ->       / \
            F   G                  *   *
                                  / \ / \
                                 F' G F G'
```

And from where do you get F' and G'? That's where recursion kicks in.

Update: In principle you're not that far off, you just have to fill in the subtrees for the multiplication:

```
Node right = this.deepCopy().getRightChild();
Node left = this.deepCopy().getLeftChild();
right.setLeftChild(derivative(this.getLeftChild()))   // F'
right.setRightChild(this.getRightChild()))            // G
left.setLeftChild(this.getLeftChild())                // F
left.setRightChild(derivative(this.getRightChild()))) // G'
```

Though I must say the API looks a bit strange. Does `deepCopy` always return the same object? Its name would suggest it makes a new copy every time.

Comment: Couldn't figure out how to properly put code in my comment, but updated my original question. Am I totally off?